# Finding text in table using match function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to use the match function in Excel using VBA.
Its giving me a mismatch error.

```
Sub pipe_size()
    Dim x As Single
    Dim y As Single
    Dim NPS As Single
    Dim Sch As String
    Dim z As Single

    NPS = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R35").Value
    Sch = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R36").Value
    'x is column number, y is row number
    x = Application.Match(NPS, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Q5:Q33"), 0)
    'y = Application.Match(Sch, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R3:AD3"), 0)

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Y34").Value = Sch
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Y35").Value = x
    'Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Y36").Value = y
End Sub
```

`NPS` is just a number but `Sch` can be a number or text. Right now, the last 3 lines are just me trying to test if Excel is picking up the right values.

`Sch` picks up the text and numbers correctly but the line

```
 y = Application.Match(Sch, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R3:AD3"), 0)
```

is giving me a type mismatch.

Comment: modify `Dim x as Variant`, and try again (same applies also to `y`)

Comment: Hi @ShaiRado, I did what you said and now it works when Sch is a text. However when Sch is a number, it returns N/A. I have the function on excel as well so I know that the match function should pick up a row number for y but it doesn't. It doesn't give an error in the code though.

Comment: Match only works on a single row or column: you can't use it on a table.  for that you need something like `Find()`

Comment: @TimWilliams, I am using it just to find the column and row number of the NPS and Sch variables. I don't think I'm referencing a table.

Comment: @Peh, do you know what might be wrong with the code?

Comment: sorry, I mis-read the range in your commented-out line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that if `Sch` is numeric and you cast it into a string with

```
Dim Sch As String
Sch = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R36").Value
```

and then you try to match the string `Sch` with `Range("R3:AD3")` this fails because there is no string `Sch` within the range but only a numeric `Sch`.

Also you should notice that there is a difference between `Application.Match` and `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`. The first one is a VBA function, the second one is the same as the worksheet function `=MATCH()` you use in worksheets.

They behave differently:

```
v = Application.Match(7, Array(1, 2, 3), 0)
```

Here the Error 2042 gets assigned to the variable `v`. No error can be caught by VBA.

But this

```
v = WorksheetFunction.Match(7, Array(1, 2, 3), 0)
```

causes a runtime error 1004 that can be caught by VBA like

```
On Error Resume Next
    v = WorksheetFunction.Match(7, Array(1, 2, 3), 0)
    Debug.Print Err.Number
On Error GoTo 0
```

---

Therefore I suggest the following:

1. Declare `NPS` and `Sch` as variant
2. Always use the `WorksheetFunction`

So we end up with this …

```
Sub pipe_size()
    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant
    Dim NPS As Variant, Sch As Variant

    NPS = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R35").Value
    Sch = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R36").Value

    'x is column number, y is row number
    On Error GoTo errorMatchX
        x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(NPS, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Q5:Q33"), 0)
    On Error GoTo errorMatchY
        y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sch, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R3:AD3"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Y34").Value = Sch
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Y35").Value = x
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Y36").Value = y

    Exit Sub

errorMatchX:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "x did not match."
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Source, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
    Exit Sub

errorMatchY:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "y did not match."
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Source, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The change to variant did it I think. Thanks! Could you please explain what you did below the exit sub in the code your wrote ? (starting from errorMatchX:)

Comment: The last part is just for normal Error Handling. The `Match` function will throw an error if it doesn't find the search therm and the code would crash. With `On Error GoTo errorMatchX` we tell VBA that if an error occurs we want to jump to `errorMatchX:` give an error message box and abort the sub with `exit sub`. Do distinguish between x and y errors we have two of them. Read [VBA Best Practices - Error Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5411/error-handling) to learn more about it.